# Como utilizar Regex en Python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Os pongo en contexto:
He realizado un par de scripts con expresiones regulares a través del módulo re de python.

```
def get_document_emails(pdf_format_content):
    """ The function runs through the document and extracts all the email addresses it finds. 
        This method returns an ordered list of document emails without repeating. """
    new_list = []
    document_emails = re.findall(r'[w.\w]*@w*.[w.\w]*', pdf_format_content)
    for i in document_emails:
        if i not in new_list and not str(i).endswith('.'):
            new_list.append(i)
    return sorted(new_list)

def get_document_provider(pdf_format_content):
    """ Return the name of the provider """
    return re.match(r'(PROVEEDOR:)+(.*?\\n)', pdf_format_content)
```

El problema surge al ejecutar la segunda función. He utilizado la biblioteca tika para extraer la información de los pdf´s y luego llamo a estas funciones para extraer los emails del documento y los datos del proveedor.

Ambas expresiones regulares las he probado en [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) y capturan lo que necesito, en el ámbito de la página web. Cuando ejecuto mis scripts en la consola, con ipython, el primero funciona de lujo pero el segundo no, he probado las funciones findall(), match(), search().. y todas devuelven NoneType o [].

La primera función trabaja sobre una cadena unicode, y devuelve sin problemas la lista de mails del documento, en formato unicode pero la segunda función no. También he probado a codificarla como utf-8 pero me da error de codificación en algunos chars, también convertirla a String con la siguiente sentencia:
**fpdf = fpdf.encode('utf-8').strip()**
Pero el resultado es el mismo, o lista vacía o NoneType..

He leído documentación del módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), navegado por la web en múltiples sitios y probado un montón de líneas de código pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado.

Lo que más me molesta es que no logro comprender por qué con los emails si funciona pero con la otra regex no.
[image: Imagen que demuestra que el patrón funciona]

En la imagen se aprecia que el patrón funciona correctamente.

[image: Ejecución scripts en consola]

En esta otra imagen muestro la salida por consola, he eliminado la info sensible pero creo que se entiende lo que quiero que veáis.
Si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar esto le estaré muy agradecido.

Thank you all!!!

**EDITO**

Después de los comentarios de los compañeros y solucionar la expresión regular dejándola así **r'(PROVEEDOR:)+(.*?\n)'** he probado a ver si lo solucionaba.

Nada más lejos de la realidad, aunque sigo sin entender por qué la primera expresión funciona y encuentra resultados y la segunda expresión no funciona, sobre la misma variable que contiene el texto en formato unicode.

Adjunto el código completo que utilizo:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re
from tika import parser


def get_pdf_content(path):
    """ Return the text content from the file given through path variable. """
    pdf = parser.from_file(path)
    return pdf['content']

def format_pdf_content(pdf_content):
    """ The method formats the content of the pdf, removes the line breaks and returns a unicode string. """
    variable = filter(lambda i: i != '\r', pdf_content)
    return "".join(variable)

def get_document_emails(pdf_format_content):
    """ The function runs through the document and extracts all the email addresses it finds. 
        This method returns an ordered list of document emails without repeating. """
    new_list = []
    document_emails = re.findall(r'[w.\w]*@w*.[w.\w]*', pdf_format_content)
    for i in document_emails:
        if i not in new_list and not str(i).endswith('.'):
            new_list.append(i)
    return sorted(new_list)

def get_document_provider(pdf_format_content):
    """ Return the name of the provider """
    return re.match(r'(PROVEEDOR:)+(.*?\r)', pdf_format_content)
```

Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte del lío inicial que tenías con respecto a si la barra debía ir doble o no, también tienes un problema con la expresión regular que usas para encontrar el proveedor, y con la función del paquete `re` que usas para ello.

Así que vamos por partes.

### El carácter `\`

Aunque creo que esto ya ha quedado claro, por si acaso lo explico con más detalle a continuación.

Dentro de una cadena entrecomillada, el carácter `\` se considera especial y su significado depende de qué carácter vaya detrás de él. Si detrás va una `n`, la pareja `\n` representa en realidad un solo carácter llamado "Newline" y cuyo ASCII es 13. Si va una `r`, la pareja `\r` es un sólo caracter llamado "carriage Return" y cuyo ASCII es 10. Estos dos caracteres suelen aparecer juntos en el orden `\r\n`, llamado también "CRLF", pero depende del operativo (en Unix es más habitual que `\n` venga solo).

Si detrás de `\` aparece otro `\`, entonces la pareja `\\` representa un sólo carácter, que es la barra inversa (ASCII 92). El hecho de que las carpetas en Windows se separen mediante `\` obliga a duplicarlos cuando aparecen dentro de una cadena Python.

También en las expresiones regulares el carácter `\` es especial para la propia expresión regular, ya que suele servir para expresar categorías de caracteres. Por ejemplo `\d` representa "dígitos". Ya que en python las expresiones regulares se guardan en cadenas, sería necesario repetir este `\` cuando se usa para especificar categorías de las expresiones regulares. Así, la expresión regular "uno o más dígitos" que sería `\d+`, en una cadena Python se escribiría `ejemplo = "\\d+"` (se duplica para quitarle su siginficado especial dentro de la cadena, de modo ques e almacene sólo uno. De este modo `len(ejemplo)` será 3, y `ejemplo[0]` sería el carácter `\`, mientras que `ejemplo[1]` sería la `d`).

Si no queremos que `\` tenga significado especial en una cadena Python, podemos usar *cadenas raw*, que van precedidas de una `r`. Esto evita tener que duplicar ese carácter cada vez que aparece, lo que puede ser útil para rutas Windows: `ruta = r'C:\Users\abulafia\Documentos\Mi Carpeta\Otra carpeta'`. A cambio perdemos la capacidad de expresar un retorno de carro, ya que `r"\n"` almacenaría la secuencia de dos caracteres `\` y `n`, en lugar de uno solo (ASCII 13).

Ya que en las expresiones regulares se usa mucho el `\`, se suelen usar *cadenas raw* para contenerlas y así evitar tener que duplicarlo. Así, la expresión regular "una secuencia de uno o más dígitos" también puede escribirse como `ejemplo = r"\d+"`, y la variable almacenaría *exactamente lo mismo* que en elc aso `ejemplo = "\\d+"`.

Para terminar de complicar las cosas, la expresión regular `r"\n"`contiene en realidad dos caracteres, pero el motor de expresiones regulares considera que los dos juntos representan el retorno de carro (de la misma forma que considear que `\d` significa "un dígito"), con lo que no hay problema en usar *cadenas raw* siempre en las expresiones regulares.

Un lío adicional ocurre si vuelcas una cadena Python por la consola. Python elige representar las cadenas cuando son volcadas en un formato que permita "copiarlas y pegarlas" como parte de un código. Así que si haces la asignación:

```
>>> ejemplo = r"\d+"
```

y vuelcas esa variable a ver qué contiene:

```
>>> ejemplo
'\\d+'
```

Python elige mostrarla como caena normal (nunca *raw*), delimitada por `'` y por tanto con cada `\` repetido, de modo que podrías copiar eso y asignarlo a otra variable, que tendría el mismo valor que la variable `ejemplo`. Pero este formato de salida confunde mucho a los usuarios, que piensan que la cadena contiene el carácter `\` repetido, cuando en realidad sólo lo contiene una vez, y es su *representación* quien lo muestra repetido.

## La expresión regular `r'(PROVEEDOR:)+(.*?\r)'`

Sobran los primeros paréntesis, pues entiendo que no quieres capturar la palabra "PROVEEDOR", sino sólo encontrarla. Lo que quieres capturar es lo que va después de ella.

El signo `+` tras esos paréntesis también parece estar mal. Ese signo significa "una o más repeticiones de lo que le precede". Pero lo que le precede es el grupo `(PROVEEDOR:)`, lo que significa que estarías buscando "Una o más repeticiones del texto `"PROVEEDOR:"` seguidas", o sea, algo como `"PROVEEDOR:PROVEEDOR:PROVEEDOR:"`. En realida ya que el caso "uno" también se admite, encontraría como válido un solo `"PROVEEDOR:"`, pero supongo que nunca aparece esa cadena repetida, por lo que el `+` sobra.

Quizás querías poner "La cadena `"PROVEEDOR:"` seguida de uno o más espacios", pero en ese caso se te olvidó poner un espacio delante del `+`, así: `(PROVEEDOR:) +`. Aunque esto obliga a que haya al menos un espacio. Si puede que no haya ninguno, es mejor usar `*` en lugar de `+`.

Finalmente viene el grupo de captura que te interesa, que es "Cualquier secuencia de caracteres *non-greedy*, hasta aparecer el primer `\r`. Esto también está mal, porque en principio puede que el `\r` no aparezca (depende del operativo el que ese carácter esté o no) y sería más seguro usar un `\n`. Y en segundo lugar porque no quieres (supongo) que el retorno de carro forme parte del resultado, por lo que mejor estaría fuera del grupo de captura. Y ya de paso quitar también del grupo de captura los hipotéticos espacios al final.

Por tanto así:

```
r"PROVEEDOR: *(.*?) *\n"
```

## La función a utilizar

Has utilizado `re.match()`, pero esta función sólo retorna un grupo *match* si la cadena coincide con la expresión regular *desde su inicio*, lo que no es tu caso  en el que lo que buscas está por el medio.

Para ese caso es mejor usar `re.search()`, suponiendo que sólo haya un proveedor, o `re.findall()` si puede haber varios.

Supongamos que sólo hay uno. `re.search()` buscará la primera ocurrencia de la expresión regular en la cadena, y te retornará un *match*. Éste contendrá la cadena completa para la que se ha producido la coincidencia (lo que incluye también el texto `"PROVEEDDOR: "` y los espacios y retornos de carro que no queremos), y también contiene los grupos de captura, que es lo que te interesa en este caso ya que el grupo de captura contendrá lo que es el nombre del proveedor solamente.

Así pues, tu función sería:

```
def get_document_provider(pdf_format_content):
    """ Return the name of the provider """
    m = re.search('PROVEEDOR: *(.*) *\n', pdf_format_content)
    if m:
       return m.groups()[0]
    else:
       return None
```

### Detalles adicionales

No veo necesaria la función que elimina los `\r`.

Tampoco es necesario en realidad incluir el `\n` dentro de la expresión regular, ya que en el grupo `.*?` el punto por defecto representa "Cualquier caracter excepto el retorno de carro", de modo que tan pronto como encuentre un retorno de carro daría por finalizado el *match* y el grupo de captura.

Por tanto creo que lo siguiente funcionará igualmente (o quizás mejor):

```
def get_document_provider(pdf_format_content):
    """ Return the name of the provider """
    m = re.search('PROVEEDOR: *(.*) *', pdf_format_content)
    if m:
       return m.groups()[0]
    else:
       return None
```

Comment: Creo que jamás me ha explicado algo tan **BIEN** como tu lo acabas de hacer. Desde luego tenía un jaleo con las barras importante, además de el/los carácter(es) _\n_ y _\r_ y los grupos en las regex.. En fin un desastre que acabas de solucionar con esta explicación tan detallada y estructurada.
Muchísimas gracias @abulafia, la gente que actúa de una forma desinteresada para ayudar a los demás se merece todo mi respeto, y por supuesto, tú te lo has ganado por completo.
Muchas gracias de nuevo máquina!! *TOP*

Comment: Me alegro de haberte aclarado las dudas. Tu comentario es para mi la mejor recompensa

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
estas agrupando provedor en resultado y escapando el salto del linea `\n` con `\\n` adicional tambien agregas el `\n` al grupo de resultado y no como caracter final debes ponerlo asi:

```
return re.findall(r'[PROVEEDOR:]+(.*?)\n', pdf_format_content)
```

**tu codigo quedaria asi:**

```
def get_document_emails(pdf_format_content):
    """ The function runs through the document and extracts all the email addresses it finds. 
        This method returns an ordered list of document emails without repeating. """
    new_list = []
    document_emails = re.findall(r'[w.\w]*@w*.[w.\w]*', pdf_format_content)
    for i in document_emails:
        if i not in new_list and not str(i).endswith('.'):
            new_list.append(i)
    return sorted(new_list)

def get_document_provider(pdf_format_content):
    """ Return the name of the provider """
    return re.match(r'[PROVEEDOR:]+(.*?)\n', pdf_format_content)
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar @Bryro !!

Comment: El patrón lo tenía mal como bien indicó @abulafia, pero parece que ya se ha solucionado. Lo que no me queda claro es por qué la búsqueda del primer patrón(emails) si funciona sobre el fichero formateado pero este otro no funciona sobre la misma variable, al intentar iterar por lineas en un bucle ( for linea in fichero:) linea es igual a un solo carácter por lo que tampoco funciona la expresión regular. Sigo sin sacar el problema..
Gracias por contestar!!!

Comment: debes editar la pregunta y agregar mas informacion entonces!