# ¿Cuál es el error de sintaxis?

Tags: python, django

Estoy agregando al archivo `settings.py` la dirección de la carpeta donde está el archivo `home.html`:

```
'DIRS': ['C:\Users\Jose\Dev\cfehome\src\templates'],
```

y obtengo el siguiente error cuando ejecuto el comando `python manage.py runserver` :

```
    'DIRS': ['C:\Users\Jose\Dev\cfehome\src\templates'],
            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: La barra inversa tiene significado especial para python cuando aparece dentro de una cadena. Para que no lo tenga pon una `r` delante de la comilla de apertura de la cadena. o tambien, (pero es más incómodo) duplica cada barra. mas información en la primera parte de esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/230167/7123

Answer (score 5):

La forma correcta de usar rutas de Windows en Django es usar la barra hacia adelante (como si fuera una ruta de Linux):

```
'DIRS': ['C:/Users/Jose/Dev/cfehome/src/templates'],
```

Con eso debe bastar.

El error surge porque estabas usando sin querer una secuencia de escape con `\U`. Esta secuencia de escape es usada para valores hexadecimales de 32 bits:

```
>>> '\U00000394'
'Δ'
>>> '\U00001497'
'ᒗ'
>>> '\U00002497'
'⒗'
>>> 'C:\Users\Jose\Dev\cfehome\src\templates'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Alternativamente puedes escapar tus barras usandolas dobles: `C:\\Users\\Jose\\Dev\\cfehome\\src\\templates`